# What feel is 12/8 meter and why?

Tags: time-signatures, meter

I know 6/8 is a two feel, so I feel like 12/8 would be a four feel of four triplet groups per bar. Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, you're exactly right. 6/8 is to 12/8 as 2/4 is to 4/4.

Now, *technically* it's not four triplets per bar. The notion of a triplet is that there are three rhythmic units in the space normally given to two of those units; thus a set of eighth-note triplets take up the space normally given to two eighth notes ( = a quarter note). But in 12/8, these three eighth notes combined to create a beat of a dotted-quarter note.

The standard description is that time signatures like 2/4 and 4/4 are called *simple meter* because their subdivisions are multiples of 2. Meters like 6/8 and 12/8, however, are *compound meters* because their subdivisions are multiples of 3.

Comment: The pulses are dotted notes it can be three quavers or a crotchet and a quaver or just a dotted crotchet. It certainly will not always be a collection of quavers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see a blues shuffle written in 12/8 time often enough.  So you can think of the "da da dum dum, da da dum dum" blues rhythm in 12/8.  It gives a triplet feel.

Comment: 'Da da dum dum' can be said to many different rhythms, so it's not too helpful to put that.'Humpty-dumpty' works quite well.